# Can I access older versions of Google Search?

Tags: search, google

I am doing a workshop that involves touching on the subject of UX to students that I am assuming have no knowledge of this area (mainly high level manager types).

I have a number of slides explaining the area, but what I would like to show them (as I believe they will be able to relate to this) is the changing face of Google Search, right the way back from the 90s to now.

The answer I am looking for:

- URL links to interactive older versions of the front end.
- If the above does not exist, some screenshots of different versions.

For those that have time, a more thorough answer involving any reference articles on why Google made changes at each version would be also very useful.

Although the [back-end search algorithms](http://www.seopalbg.com/blog/how-google-changed-over-the-years/) do impact the user experience, I would like to concentrate on the front-end layout, and talk through some of the changes that have come about.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**
Correction to the above.
Although the [very front end of Google has changed over time](http://web.archive.org/web/19990508044928/http://www2.google.com/), I now realise that actually I need to gain access to historical pages that are initially returned on submitting a search query to Google.  e.g. [Search for Pizza in google today.](https://www.google.com/search?q=pizza&rlz=1C1_____en-GBAU451AU451&sugexp=chrome,mod=17&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: If you're looking for old front end code, minus pictures, The Wayback Machine generally covers it

Comment: Something like this? http://www.businessinsider.com/look-at-how-much-google-search-has-changed-since-1998-2012-2?op=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can find interactive versions of every change google has made in his algorithms.

Althrough you can find around 8600 screenshots since its starts in 1998 here:

```
http://wayback.archive.org/web/19980915000000*/http://google.com
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

An interactive map of different versions is difficult to come by, especially if you want to have the old algorithms as well. I think this is only possible to find at guarded Google Plex code repository, out of reach for us Google users.

> If the above does not exist, some screenshots of different versions.

Still, there are a [14 screenshots available from this article](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2006-04-21-n63.html), which is interesting from a design / UX perspective. Fromm the first one in **1997**:

[image: Google screenshot 1997]

... through the design of **2002**:

[image: Google screenshot 2002]

... to the clean design of **2009**:

[image: Google screenshot 2009]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access it. If I understood correctly, you want to use the 'old' version of Google search algorithm to compare results with the currently one, right? If is something like that what you want, I would say that is not possible. These follow links http://www.floridatechnologyjournal.com/features/42-rokstories/1061-history-of-google-algorithm-changes-infographic and http://www.seomoz.org/google-algorithm-change can give you some insights about the algorithm changes.

Comment: "Although the back-end search algorithms do impact the user experience, I would like to concentrate on the front-end layout"  Happy to get screenshots of results from different versions, but ideally consistent search terms.  e.g. search for pizza.

Comment: So, if the position of keywords in SERP is not your goal and you only want to see the front-end, I think your best shoot is to try to search for images (screenshots) of search results. Something like this http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008_09_01_archive.html